# How can Android use the app compat components automatically?

Tags: android

Recently I'm studying the usage of the appcompat support library and the design support library. And I met a strange question(at least for me) that I can't understand. 
In the appcompat support library, there're several AppCompat* like components, such as AppCompatButton, AppCompatCheckBox... There's one same thing among these components - In the official doc all these components have such illustration,

> This will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts.
>   You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom
>   views.

or something like this.

Here come's the question. Since Button isn't AppCompatButton, how can it consider it as AppCompatButton when I use Button during the xml or created in code? How does it work?

Forgive my Cantonese English.

Comment: instead of `Button` use somethig like `android,support.v4.widget.Button`

Comment: AppCompatButton is a subclass of Button, only it is tint-aware https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html. A layout is just a template; when inflated under AppCompatActivity, the Button is "transformed" into AppCompatButton. When inflated under the normal Activity, the Button stays unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Short brief on how the AppComp decided which class to init - 
When using the support library (AppCompat) using the support library widgets (e.g. android,support.v4.widget.Button) ,the library will use the appropriate implementation based on your Android OS.
For example ,if your OS support Button it will use the native implementation ,else it will use the AppCompat implementation.
In other words ,it defers to run time to decide what to use..
I assume this is the automatically part..

Comment: Any reference to the approach?